# Excel VBA Match function

Tags: vba, excel, match, evaluate

A `Match.Evaluate` function in my codes doesn't work unfortunately.

Below you can see the formula:

```
Worksheet_Bilgiler = "Egitim Bilgileri"
Ders_Adi = "Deneme1"

Ders_Satir_bul = Worksheets(Worksheet_Bilgiler).Evaluate("=Match(" & Ders_Adi & ", '" & Worksheet_Bilgiler & "'!C:C, 0)")

MsgBox Ders_Satir_bul
```

Can you guys help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add double quote sign `"` before and after your `Ders_Adi` variable. You can do that by using `Chr(34)`.

Change your `Evaluate` line to :

```
Ders_Satir_bul = Worksheets(Worksheet_Bilgiler).Evaluate("=Match(" & Chr(34) & Ders_Adi & Chr(34) & ", '" & Worksheet_Bilgiler & "'!C:C, 0)")
```

Comment: Thank you so much man. Worked like a charm!

Comment: @Bildircin13 you're welcome :)

Comment: Just a tip, `Evaluate` can be reduced to **`[Formula]`**, for example `[SUM(Sheet1!A1:A10)]`